# Stopping TeamCity build when specific file is in the commit

Tags: git, build, teamcity

I have a Build Configuration that I don't want to run if a file called RELEASE_NOTES.md is included in the change. (I have a separate build config that fires when that is included).

I've tried adding 
    -:RELEASE_NOTES.md 
into my VCS trigger and if it's the **ONLY** file in the change then it doesn't fire, but any other files included mean it still fires.

How do I add the trigger to say if the file is there, regardless of other files, don't run the build?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

You could write a TeamCity plugin that cancels the build. Such a plugin can get at the commits that triggered the build, can analyse them, and detect that your `RELEASE_NOTES.md` was modified - and then cancel the build.

However, maybe you should reconsider your approach. Why must you avoid the normal (non-release) build? Is it expensive, so you can't afford to run both the release and non-release one?

Comment: The release creates a nuget package, I don't want the CI build creating nuget packages un-necessarily on every checkin.

Comment: I am asking about the reverse: why must you prevent running the non-release build when you're releasing?

Comment: I guess I don't need to, but it's superfluous, it means a build process will run twice.

Comment: Can you separate your release build into a common part (which would run always) and a release-only part (which would produce the nuget packages)?